# Can't see DVD drive in Windows 8 Developer Preview

Tags: optical-drive, windows-8-preview

After installing the Windows 8 Developer Preview (64-bit) on my PC, I can no longer see my DVD drive. What could be wrong?

**My PC specifications:**

- Gigabyte GA-EP41T-UD3L (G41) motherboard
- Samsung DVD (connected via SATA)
- Intel Core 2 Duo 2.93GHz
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series 1GB

The "Hide Empty Drives" option has been Unchecked, but had no effect.

Comment: You included all the information except the most important one. Your DVD bone is connected to the SATA bone, which is connected to the **Motherboard** bone. . .

Comment: sorry  my DVD is Samsung (SATA) and the Motherboard is Gigabyte Ep41T-UD3l (G41)

Comment: You can't see the DVD drive (which may be an explorer option for 'Hide Empty Drives'), or the DVD drive doesn't show up in the 'Device Manager' of the desktop version of control panel (ie: not the metro one)?

Comment: DVD drives (almost) never don't need an additional driver, the generic one(s) in Windows should be fine.  Does it show up in your BIOS?  Are you sure it was working before you install Win8?

Comment: I'm sure 100% that it was working before i install Win8. And also i installed Windows 8 using it.

Comment: Weird, it looks like you're not the only one running into this. Another user just asked this same question (we voted it as a dupe of this one), and he can boot back to Win7 and it still works..   Pre-beta's do weird things I guess. ;)

Comment: @surfasb... "bone"?

Comment: I had the same problem with a SATA DVD drive with Windows Home Server.  Never did figure out the problem.  Wonder if they borrowed some base code from there.

Comment: You realize this is pre-beta software? Who knows what will work or not work on any given hardware.

Comment: try the Consumer Preview and see if the issue is still there?

Comment: There are a lot of people that complain about the cd-rom drive missing. After installing myself Win 9 CP, the drive worked fine and after a few days... the drive is still missing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows8 is still in its infancy, and many drivers are not yet stable enough to deploy to Windows8. Unfortunately this means that you will not be able to use your drive on the Windows8 CP until either the Windows8 RC or unless the manufacturer of the drive releases drivers compatible with the Win8 CP.