# Windows 8 developer preview DVD Rom/Burner not working

Tags: windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't see DVD drive in Windows 8 Developer Preview](https://superuser.com/questions/336749/cant-see-DVD-drive-in-Windows-8-developer-preview)

This is driving me crazy.
Dual booting Windows 7 and Windows 8. Everything works but the DVD ROM in Windows 8. It does not show up in Device Manager. I've tried multiple installs and burn speeds of the Windows 8 ISO and still no DVD ROM in device manager. It shows in BIOS just fine and works in Windows 7 just fine. Drives in Windows Explorer are not hidden. I can't think of anything else to try. Anyone else have this issue that could point me in the correct direction to fix it?