# Can't install Windows 8 Developer Preview

Tags: installation, drivers, dvd, windows-8-preview

I've burnt the Windows 8 Developer Preview DVD and inserted it into my laptop. Setup starts and looks good, but it then prompts me for a DVD driver. Saying it is missing.

I can't progress further than this. There is no dedicated DVD driver to download for my laptop.

Is this normal?

Comment: USB all the way. 8GB flash drives sell for the price of a latte these days.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't see DVD drive in Windows 8 Developer Preview](http://superuser.com/questions/336749/cant-see-dvd-drive-in-windows-8-developer-preview)

Comment: @Moab You need to leave out the space between the @ and the username to make the notification work, by the way.

Comment: @techie007, not a duplicate, that one is after the OS is installed, not during installation

Comment: @JL, Usually this means the ISO you used was corrupt, or the burn job is corrupt, but not always.

Comment: @Moab, no the ISO was not corrupt. I tried it both x86 and x64, and the x86 version worked.

Comment: ISO or Burn job corruption can cause it, but they are not the only cause, just the most common. I have seen some solved by installing from USB flash drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please be aware that it is pre-release software, there will be problems with drivers. As an alternative, try using the [USB installation method](http://www.windows8geek.com/2011/04/how-to-install-windows-8-from-usb-drive/)

Comment: You can also try using [virtualization](http://superuser.com/questions/335508/which-virtual-machine-software-is-preferable-for-running-windows-8-developer-prev) if your processor supports.

Answer (score 2):

You can also run the partition-enabled (non-upgrade) installer from inside windows by mounting the ISO and starting  `\sources\setup.exe`

Comment: Woo! After days {well, maybe less} of searching, I found my answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to provide proper/updated IDE/SATA/RAID controller drivers before starting the install so that the Setup can continue to see the drive(s) after the install has switched over from the generic startup driver(s).

See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasetup/thread/4d906f85-7650-4eff-8bd2-13ec2b0bd2ae/) for similar problems people had when Vista first came out.