# Windows 8 won't show my DVD Drive

Tags: windows-8-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't see DVD drive in Windows 8 Developer Preview](https://superuser.com/questions/336749/cant-see-dvd-drive-in-windows-8-developer-preview)

I have installed Windows 8 Developer preview, but it won't show my DVD Drive in my computer.

What is the problem?

(I don't know which information about my computer is useful, if you need information, please let me know in comments)

Edit : DVD Drive isn't exists in Device manager. Also I have a windows 7 on same machine, and windows 7 shows DVD drive correctly.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried putting a disc in the drive?

Comment: @IUnknown Yes but still there is no DVD drive in My Computer

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to inspect the [Device Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Device-Manager) to see whether it appears there.

1. **Does it appear?** Try to disable and enable it, or remove and detect it again.
2. **Doesn't it appear?**

   - Try to scan for new hardware devices.
   - Or... Shut down your computer, switch the SATA ports and reboot your computer, scan again.

This should get you somewhat to figure out where the device is stuck, and might make Windows show it.

Comment: I have updated the question.